# Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Offset'

Tags: json, flutter, dart, encoding, server

I'm trying to send Dart Offset points by encoding it to Json format using 'dart:convert' library.
I have gone through the documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html.

The error I'm getting is for serializing the inbuilt classes.

```
The following JsonUnsupportedObjectError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Offset'
```

How can i serialize inbuilt class like Offset and Paint class, is this the correct way to send the data to server?

TestData class contains Offset point and toJson() function

```
class TestData {
  TestData(this.point);
  Offset point;

  toJson() {
    return{
      'point': point,
    };
  }
}
```

Encoder function

```
String jsonEncoder() {
    Map testDataMap = this.testDataObj.toJson();
    String jsonStringData = jsonEncode(testDataMap);
    return jsonStringData;
}
```

Comment: I would do it explicitly: return{
      'point': {dx: "$point.dx", dy: "$point.dy"},
    };

Comment: Thanks. I implemented using this method and it worked.

Comment: Hello @snapshot, can I post it as the solution?

Comment: Yes @camillo777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would return the JSON explicitly:

```
return { 'point': {dx: "$point.dx", dy: "$point.dy"}, };
```